# Manually write CMakeLists using CMake GUI

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

Is it possible to replace  a manually written CMakeLists.txt with CCMake (CMake GUI) generated CMakeLists.txt?

It seems that it is not interoperable with manually created cmake.txt, is it true?

Comment: just edit it, it's a text file anyway, any text editor will do. as for the ohter way around, as long as you follow the CMakeLists.txt structure, cmake GUI would be able to load it.

Comment: What do you mean with portable? CMake is portable, ccmake is portable, editing CMakeLists files with editors is portable.

Comment: @usr1234567 : **interoperability** between cmake generated by cmake-gui & manually written cmake text

Comment: @LeleDumbo try you can not import manually written cmake to cmake-GUI !

Comment: there you go: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22124591/Videos/manual-gui.flv
anything else to say?

Comment: this is the same but with ccmake: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22124591/Videos/with-ccmake.flv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. All you can edit with ccmake are variables and their values.

ccmake is meant to edit the configuration, not for development of CMakeFiles. The latter is not for users but for developers. Edit these files by a good editor or an IDE with CMake support like KDevelop, QtCreator et al.

Comment: [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) has a very impressive CMake integration that allows seamless back and forth between their GUI and the CMake source.

Comment: @usr1234567  if your configuration mean cmake text note if only can edit own generated configuration

Comment: @maziarnavahan: I don't understand your remark. Have you confused CMakeLists.txt that controls the configuration and CMakeCache.txt that contains the cached variables and their values? If you ment the latter, please edit your question. Then I have to answer differently.